# How can I implement a vector class which can store any type of variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, vector

I'm writing a class that partially reimplement the vector class from C++ standard library. But I don't know how to implement it to be able to store any type of variable.

I was using templates to solve the problem, but when I run the program, which store the value in double, the output will come out an int. For example, myVector(2,2.2) and the output is 2 2, but not 2.2 2.2 what I expected. Can someone tell me where did I do wrong?

this is my myVector.h file:

```
#ifndef MYVECTOR_H
#define MYVECTOR_H

template<class T> class myVector {
private:
    T *arrPtr;
    int storage; // the size of the array
    int currentSize; // the size of the array which has values

public:
    myVector(int nOfElement,T values);

    T& indexOfArray(int index);
        void printArray();

    ~myVector();
};

#endif
```

`this is myVector.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myVector.h"

using namespace std;


template <class T> myVector<T>::myVector(int nOfElement, T values){
  storage = nOfElement;
    arrPtr = new T[storage];

    for (int i = 0; i < storage; i++) {
        arrPtr[i] = values;
    }
    currentSize = storage;
}


//return a refernece to the specific index of the array
template <class T> T& myVector<T>::indexOfArray(int index)
{
    if (index < 0 || index >= currentSize) {
        cout << "Error: The index is larger than the size" << endl;
    delete[] arrPtr;
        exit(0);
    }
    return arrPtr[index];
}


template <class T> void myVector<T>::printArray(){
  for (int i = 0; i < currentSize; i++){
    cout << indexOfArray(i) << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;
}


int main() {

  myVector<int> v3(3,2.2);

  // testing for v3
  cout << "Testing for v3:" << endl; 
  v3.printArray();

  return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: `v3` is a `myVector<int>`. Why do you expect it to be storing `double`s? The same thing would happen if you had a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: I thought I set it in type T, which can store in any type? What should I do if I want myVector to be storing in any type not only int?

Comment: Given `myVector<int>` `T == int`. Are you expecting it to store multiple types in the same container?

Comment: yes, I am expecting myVector can store either int or double

Comment: Then you're looking at not only reimplementing `std::vector`, but `std::variant` or even `std::any`.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. In C++ the types of all objects are known ***at compile time***. This is fundamental to C++, there are no workarounds or exceptions. This is true even with `std::any`, which allegedly holds anything, but you still have to define at compile time what it holds every time it's referenced; otherwise you can't use it, in any way.